# How to pass batch data to controller action from kendo UI grid in case of batch editing?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datagrid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to implement the kendo grid in my mvc 3 apps. I'm interested in batch editing. I need to send batch data from view to controller action method.

Here is my code for view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    This is Home!!
</title>

<link href="../../Content/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="../../Content/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.metro.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "EmployeeID",
                fields: {
                    EmployeeID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    EmployeeName: { validation: { required: true } }

                }
            }
        },
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Home/GetData",
                type: "GET"
            },
            update: {
                url: "/Home/Update",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json'
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "/Home/Destroy",
                type: "POST"
            },


            create: {
                url: "/Home/Create",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json'
            },


            pageSize: 20,


            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            }
        }

    });





    $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            navigatable: true,
            pageable: true,
            height: 430,
            sortable: true,
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            columns: [

                { field: "EmployeeID", title: "Employee ID", width: 110 },
                { field: "EmployeeName", title: "Employee Name", width: 110 },

                { command: "destroy", title: "Delete", width: 90 }],
            editable: true,
            selectable: "multiple row",
            groupable: true,
            navigatable: true
        });
    });



</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="grid"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller code:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Update(List<Employee> model) //Parameter gets no data.
 {
     var obj = new Employee();
     //return View();
     return Json(obj);
 }

//Parameter gets no data.
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<Employee> model) 
{
   return View("Index");
}
```

if I'm not wrong, I'm doing something wrong in parameter mapping or the signature of the action method, can't figure out what? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is that you did not say that it needs to be batch so you are actually sending the data to the server as soon as you finish editing the `EmployeeName` (exit edit mode) **but** your `parameterMap` function is incorrect when sending in non-batch mode because then there is no *`model`* in `options` (just directly the data).

So, either add `batch: true` to the `DataSoure` definition (if you want to go in `batch` mode):

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    batch: true,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "EmployeeID",
            fields: {
                EmployeeID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                EmployeeName: { validation: { required: true } }

            }
        }
    },
    ...
```

or change `parameter` map to return `options` (only if you don't want to go with `batch`):

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
    if (operation !== "read") {
        return options;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did add the batch attribute & now I'm able to pass the data to the controller. But Firebug showing me, when I'm trying to update multiple data, its creating multiple httppost request, I think it should be one single http tour, isn't it?

Comment: Right, it should issue just one http. I've used your same code (the only difference is that I've used php but that should not make any difference).

Comment: BTW: why do you a jquery version that is not the one distributed together KendoUI, that uses to be a source of problems. As far as possible try to stick to whatever they ship

Comment: Thanks for the point, anyway I still a bit far from the solution. I'm still not able to send multiple data in a single request although I did add the batch attribute & when I'm trying to catch multiple data in the controller action method by setting the parameter as list, it receives no data! I'm trying to figure these issues, Please let me know if you have any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: For batch editing, is it enough to just add the batch attribute or I need to change my parametermap function as well. If so, can you please show me the signature of that method. I was trying to loop thorough the options parameter, but no luck! I assume the options parameter holds the data from the grid, isn't it?

Comment: Your parameter function is actually sending a JSON object so you need to get it and convert it to an object (for example: List<Employee>). There is little I can help on ASP or C#, I work in Java and PHP. Did you check what you are transmitting using Firebug or equivalent in your browser? It should show you what type of data is being transmitted and that should help you writing the appropriate service.

Comment: Its sending different http request carrying only the last modified data! I can understand, that I need to extract the json object, but first I need to send multiple record in json format in a single request.

Comment: No, you send only one that is an array and the array contains multiple records with the modified data. You will have one request to the server containing all new, another with all deleted and another will all modified.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried every option I found on the web the only one that worked for me was this

```
public ActionResult Products_Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> products)
{
    // Will keep the updated entitites here. Used to return the result later.
    var entities = new List<Product>();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var northwind = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            foreach (var product in products)
            {
                // Create a new Product entity and set its properties from the posted ProductViewModel.
                var entity = new Product
                {
                    ProductID = product.ProductID,
                    ProductName = product.ProductName,
                    UnitsInStock = product.UnitsInStock
                };
                // Store the entity for later use.
                entities.Add(entity);
                // Attach the entity.
                northwind.Products.Attach(entity);
                // Change its state to Modified so Entity Framework can update the existing product instead of creating a new one.
                northwind.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                // Or use ObjectStateManager if using a previous version of Entity Framework.
                // northwind.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
            }
            // Update the entities in the database.
            northwind.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    // Return the updated entities. Also return any validation errors.
    return Json(entities.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState, product => new ProductViewModel
    {
        ProductID = product.ProductID,
        ProductName = product.ProductName,
        UnitsInStock = product.UnitsInStock
    }));
}
```

This example I've pulled from Telerik site http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editing/batch-editing

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Set in transport 'update' content type header to:

```
'contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",'
```

And use in parameterMap option either:

```
return kendo.stringify({ models: options.models });
```

or

```
return JSON.stringify({ models: options.models });
```